# How do I sort product images by media type in Shopify's GraphQL library?

Tags: graphql, shopify

I am trying to rearrange my Shopify images. I want to display GLBs at the top. I am having trouble selecting MODEL_3D glb files because MODEL_3D models have no gid! Only the preview jpg has a preview, and it is invalid to position using the reorderProductMedia mutation. So I was thinking of reordering by a Media-type query to display the GLBs at the top. Any advice?